# Is it okay to make Integer-keyed Maps in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, indexing

Just like in title. Is it okay to make something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> foo = new HashMap<>();
```

Or maybe there's better container that allow adding values at any index? When saying "better" I mean "having better performance", and then "having less RAM usage".

```
ArrayList<Object> bar = new ArrayList<>();
bar.add(10_000, new Object());
```

A want to do something like in this code above, but this of course doesn't work with ArrayList. The list that I want to make is sparse; the indexes are spread - that's why I was thinking about HashMap and not ArrayList.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use the HashMap like you describe. This can be done for instance to create a "sparse" array.

Comment: You can do that without a problem, however beware that integers will _not_ be sorted; if you want them sorted, use a `TreeMap`. If you are looking for some alternative with better performance, GNU Trove can help.

Comment: I know I can do it, but I'm asking if there's any better way :) Thanks @fge, I'll look at this GNU Trove (although I prefer built-in classes :) )

Comment: "better" is a subjective term.  "better" in terms of what criteria?

Comment: You mention "inserting at any index". What is it you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: @jtahlborn "better" for me means at first place "faster". When there can't be anything faster, "better" means for me "having less RAM usage".

Comment: If you're looking for a sparse array, that sounds like you're after performance. Trove works with primitive arrays, which gives it significant advantage both in performance and memory usage.

Comment: awesome.  since no one else but you is you, it helps to add such criteria to your question.

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks, I added that information! :)

Comment: If you want to use less RAM, consider using TIntObjectHashMap which supports a primitive `int` key, instead of an `Integer` wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing (in effect) is to use `HashMap` to represent a sparse array.

This can be a reasonable implementation choice, but its efficacy depends on what you are trying to achieve, and on the properties of the array.

If the array is sparse enough, then you will save memory by using a `HashMap` instead of a simple array.  However compared to a non-sparse array, a `HashMap` uses roughly an order of magnitude *more* memory than an array.  On top of that, the `get` and `put` operations on a `HashMap` are roughly an order of magnitude slower than indexing a simple array.

Also, depending on the size and sparseness of the array, there are representations that use significantly *less* space than a `HashMap` (e.g. the Android sparse array classes) at the cost of get/put performance that doesn't scale as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your questions is very generic, and from details you have specified it seems both HashMap and ArrayList fit your requirement and you are only bothered about performance. Performance has various aspects:

1. If your data is contiguous or less spread[i.e integers are more or less in sequence] then i would go for ArrayList as cost of insertion is less as compared to HashMap.
2. If your data has lots of spread or if you are going to perform lots of deleteion also along with insertion then i would go for HashMap.

So it depends on your requirement.

EDIT:
If data has lots of spread then HashMap is the way to go. If you use Array or ArrayList then your memory consumption will become high due to lots of gaps in between storage of data. HashMap cost of insertion is higher than Array but then as you are concerened about RAM , you should go with HashMap.

Comment: My data has lots of spread :) I added that information to the question.

Comment: see my Edit. I would go with HashMap.